# HTTPS redirect keeps resulting in loop - IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, https

First time poster here. I am having an issue forcing a specific site to https. What I have tried are multiple url rewrite code blocks in the web.config to force it to https, but every time I try, I keep getting the loop. 
The reason I am getting the loop, I believe is because another company owns the url and it is getting redirected to us. Here is what I think is happening:

- The URL, lets say test.othercompany.com is redirected on their end to
  a load balancer DNS name that we own.
- After the request hits the load balancer it is directed to our IIS
  server(s) where we have the binding in place for
  test.othercompany.com on the site.
- With the https rewrite in place it will take the
  http://www.test.othercompany.com site, redirect it to
  https://www.test.othercompany.com, which in my opinion, would then
  redirect it up to the other company's nameservers, which would then
  redirect it to us again, thus this is where the loop comes into play.

Am I correct with this assumption?

I am trying to find any way to force this to https without getting this loop. Any ideas or suggestions? I'm also open to any troubleshooting ideas also. I tried using Fiddler, but it just shows me the loops and that is about it from what I can see.

Here are the configs that I have tried so far, that gave me the loop:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

and also this one:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="TM_HTTP_TO_HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <!--IF HOST IS TEST.OTHERCOMPANY.COM -->
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.test\.othercompany\.com$" ignoreCase="true" />

              <!--IF REQUESTED URL IS ON HTTP PROTOCOL MEANS NON SECURE PORT (PORT!=443) -->
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^443$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <!--Redirect ON HTTPS PROTOCOL -->
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thank you.